# Julia: Products of sequences in a vectorized way

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, julia, array-broadcasting

Learning to pass from Python to Julia, I am trying to convert an old code that I have, that is calculating a product of sequence of this expression:

[image]

I have two versions of the code in Python, one implemented with `for` loops, and the other using broadcasting. The `for` loop version is:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(1.,5.,1)
G = np.array([[1.,2.],[3.,4.]])

def calcF(G,A):
    N = A.size
    print A
    print N
    F = []
    for l in range(N):
        F.append(G/A[l])
        print F[l]
        for j in range(N):
            if j != l:
                F[l]*=((G - A[l])/(G + A[j]))*((A[l] - A[j])/(A[l] + A[j]))
    return F

F= calcF(G,A)
print F
```

And the vectorized version I have learned from a response to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696179/product-of-a-sequence-in-numpy/34697017#34697017), is this function:

```
def calcF_vectorized(G,A):
    # Get size of A
    N = A.size

    # Perform "(G - A[l])/(G + A[j]))" in a vectorized manner
    p1 = (G - A[:,None,None,None])/(G + A[:,None,None])

    # Perform "((A[l] - A[j])/(A[l] + A[j]))" in a vectorized manner
    p2 = ((A[:,None] - A)/(A[:,None] + A))

    # Elementwise multiplications between the previously calculated parts
    p3 = p1*p2[...,None,None]

    # Set the escaped portion "j != l" output as "G/A[l]"
    p3[np.eye(N,dtype=bool)] = G/A[:,None,None]

    Fout = p3.prod(1)

    # If you need separate arrays just like in the question, split it
    return np.array_split(Fout,N)
```

I tried to naively translate the Python `for` loops code to Julia:

```
function JuliacalcF(G,A)
    F = Array{Float64}[]
    for l in eachindex(A)
        push!(F,G/A[l])
        println(A[i])
        for j in eachindex(A)
            if j!=l
                F[l]*=((G - A[l])/(G + A[j]))*((A[l] - A[j])/(A[l] + A[j]))
            end
        end
    end
    #println(alpha)
    return F
end
A = collect(1.0:1.0:5.0)
G = Vector{Float64}[[1.,2.],[3.,4.]]
println(JuliacalcF(G,A))
```

But is there a way to do it in a smart way as in the `numpy` broadcasting vectorized version?

Comment: Are you sure you need a vectorized version? If you're interested in performance (and _probably_ vectorizing) I'd recommend you first [profile](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/profile/) your code and take a look at [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/)

Answer (score 1):

Also, take a look at [More-Dots](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julialang.github.com/blob/master/blog/_posts/moredots/More-Dots.ipynb) and [Loop Fusion](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots) where vectorization is described with examples.